# how to modify the background of a select2 when no value is captured

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 which is as follows:

```
<section>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col col-2">ConceptoPrueba</label>
                                    <div class="col col-10">
                                        <select name="Prueba" id="Prueba" style="width: 100%" class="select2" runat="server">
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
```

And when I do not capture value, I want it to change color red indicating that it is mandatory
I have this in the validation works:

```
 function Validar() {
            if ($("#ctl00_contenido_Prueba").val() == null || $("#ctl00_contenido_Prueba").val() == "0") {
                ShowError("Concepto", "El concepto es obligatorio.");
                $('#ctl00_contenido_Prueba').parent().removeClass('state-success').addClass("state-error");
                $('#ctl00_contenido_Prueba').removeClass('valid');
            }};
```

the validation is correct but I do not reliza the change of color someone can support me

Answer (score 0):

- I didn't see any *#ctl00_contenido_Prueba* id in your HTML code
- To get the value from select:

> $( "#Prueba" ).val();

Comment: I am using an asp: content which contains the definitions ContentPlaceHolderID = "content" for my id:

Comment: For the moment add uns style
.borderred {
            border-color: #a90329;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: solid;
        }
command call this way for the select2
$('.select2').addClass("borderred");